plot raster file with terra
The code below works fine to map a raster file with species data (25 m spatial resolution).
Question: I am strugglin around differentiating between values outside the map (background, also treated as 0) and the real 0 values within the map.

# Load required libraries
library(terra)          # for handling raster files

# Load the raster file
raster_data <- rast("pollinator.tif")

# Define categories and breaks
 breaks <- seq(0, 0.03, length.out = 6) # 5 categories, so 6 breaks
categorized_raster <- classify(raster_data, rcl = cbind(breaks[-length(breaks)], 
breaks[-1], 1:5))

# Handle background (outside map) values separately
background_value <- -1  # Assign a distinct value for the background
categorized_raster[is.na(values(categorized_raster))] <- background_value

# Define custom colors
 colors <- c("white", "#fde725", "#5ec962", "#21918c", "#3b528b", "#440154") # Add 
 white for background

# Adjust the color assignment to include the background
# "white" (background) is mapped to -1, followed by the defined category colors
 plot(categorized_raster, col = colors, main = "Pollinator Abundance (Andrena 
 strohmella, Spring)",
 xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", axes = TRUE, legend = TRUE)


Can you please edit your question to make the code a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. That is, do not use your own data but use data created with code or data that ships with R. For example start with r <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra").

Example data
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
x <- classify(r, 5) |> as.int()

The obvious solution is to not use "white" as a color for your data
colors <- c("#fde725", "#5ec962", "#21918c", "#3b528b", "#440154") 
plot(x, col=colors)

But if you do, you can set the background (NA) color to something else, "light gray" in this example.
colors <- c("white", "#fde725", "#5ec962", "#21918c", "#3b528b", "#440154") 
plot(x, col=colors, colNA="light gray")


